# O que é exatamente o seletor elemento.classe?

Tags: css

Eu estava desenvolvendo e uma coisa me chamou bastante a atenção: a regra `elemento .classe` é diferente de `elemento.classe`.

Percebi que a principal diferença é que a primeira poderia ser lida assim: "Elemento que tenha um filho com a classe `classe`" e a segunda: "Elemento que contenha a classe `classe`". Gostaria de explicações sobre essa segunda, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em uma breve explicação;

O `elemento .classe` equivale há `elemento *.classe`, o vazio é uso "abreviado" do asterisco `*`, que serve para aplicar CSS a todos elementos, por exemplo:

- `* {}` aplica estilo a qualquer elemento html da página
- `html > *` aplica aos elementos filhos de `<html>`, por exemplo `<head>` e `<body>`, não afetas os "netos"
- `*.exemplo` ou `.exemplo` afetam todos elementos que possuírem o atributo `class` com o valor `exemplo` separado por espaço de outro, por exemplo:

  ```
  <div class="test exemplo abc"></div>
  ```
- `div *.exemplo` irá afetar *qualquer elemento* dentro de uma `<div>` que possuir a classe:

  ```
  <div>
      <span class="test exemplo">test</span>
  </div>

  <div>
      <p>
         <span class="test exemplo">test</span>
      </p>
  </div>
  ```

Já o `elemento.classe` é parecido com o anterior, mas com um elemento especifico:

Por exemplo, `span.test`, irá afetar apenas os spans:

```css
div span.exemplo {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>
       <span class="test exemplo">Será afetado</span><br>
       <strong class="test exemplo">Não será afetado</strong><br>
       <sub class="test exemplo">Não será afetado</sub><br>
       <span class="test exemplo">Será afetado</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

### Negando alguns elementos

Se você quiser que qualquer elemento use uma regra CSS, menos o `sub` por exemplo, você pode usar o `:not()`, por exemplo:

```css
#main *.test:not(sub) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <p>
       <span class="test exemplo">Será afetado</span><br>
       <strong class="test exemplo">Será afetado</strong><br>
       <sub class="test exemplo">Não erá afetado</sub><br>
    </p>
</div>
```

Leia mais em:

- [CSS2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/)
- [CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-roadmap-20010523/)

Comment: Excelente resposta, tirou todas as dúvidas que tinha, obrigado :)

Comment: Obrigado @RafaelAlmeida!