# O que significa o ">" nos seletores CSS?

Tags: css, css3

Galera, me deparei com esse CSS de um projeto free que baixei da web.

```
.user-panel>.image>img {}
```

1. O que essa notação "aninhada" representa?
2. Porque o "img" não tem o ponto (.)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os pontos são usados para classes. Os elementos HTML usam-se só com o seu nome. O simbolo `>` quer dizer descendente imediato.

Outras maneiras de ler esse seletor seria assim:

```
elemento com classe "user-panel" 
    que tem um descendente direto 
        elemento com classe "image"
            que tem um descendente direto
                elemento HTML "img"
```

As regras de CSS serão aplicadas somente ao elemento `img` que respeita esse hierarquia/estrura de HTML.

Em HTML poderia ser:

```
<div class="user-panel">
    <div class="image">
       <img src="..." />
```

Comment: Creio ser duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre os seletores "element element" e "element>element"?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2256/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-os-seletores-element-element-e-elementelement) e [O que é exatamente o seletor elemento.classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58001/3635), claro que combinadas.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento verdade, combinadas respondem à pergunta. Já tinha dado `+1` em tudo lá nessas respostas. Com os links aqui que colocaste na pergunta fica tudo organizado.

Answer (score 1):

Este seletor quer dizer:

> Selecione todos elementos com a classe **.user-panel**, depois selecione todos filhos diretos com a classe **.image**, depois selecione todos os filhos diretos que sejam a tag **img**.

Ou seja:

- **.user-panel**: Seletor por classe
- **>**: Indicador de descendente direto (filho)
- **.image**: Seletor por classe
- **>**: Indicador de descendente direto (filho)
- **img**: Seletor por tag

### Referências:

- [Seletor por classe](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)
- [Elemento>Elemento](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp)
- [Seletor por tag](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element.asp)

Comment: Obrigado pessoal!