# Qual a diferença na declaração dessas duas opçoes?

Tags: css

1- isso

```
.back.flipped
```

e diferente disso?

```
.flipped
```

2- isso

```
.front.flipped
```

e diferente disso?

```
.back.flipped
```

Answer (score 4):

Classes em HTML dentro do atributo `class=""` são delimitadas por espaços e no CSS são delimitadas por ponto (`.`), uma classe no CSS que contenha `.foo.bar` ou `.bar.foo` (independente da ordem) irá buscar no HTML algo como:

```
<div class="foo bar">
<div class="bar foo">
<div class="foo bar baz">
<div class="baz foo bar">
```

Podendo possuir mais classes ou não dentro do atributo `class=` ainda sim irá ser reconhecido pelo CSS

O `.flipped` busca qualquer elemento que tenha a classe `flipped`, exemplos:

```css
.flipped {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipped">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="flipped ">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class=" flipped">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class=" flipped ">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class=" flipped     ">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="flipped bar">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="flipped bar baz">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="flipped bar bar">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="bar flipped">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="bar baz flipped">fica em vermelho</div>
<div class="outro">não é afetado</div>
```

Já o `.back.flipped` (ou invertido `.flipped.back`) busca elementos como:

```css
.back.flipped {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipped back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="back flipped">fica em azul</div>
<div class=" flipped back">fica em azul</div>
<div class=" flipped      back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="flipped bar back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="flipped bar baz back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="flipped bar bar back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="bar flipped back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="bar baz flipped back">fica em azul</div>
<div class="outro">não é afetado</div>
```

O mesmo é com o `.front.flipped` (ou `.front.flipped`), como:

```css
.front.flipped {
    color: #fc0;
}
```

```html
<div class="flipped front">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="back front">não é afetado</div>
<div class=" flipped front">fica em laranja</div>
<div class=" flipped      front">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="flipped bar front">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="flipped bar front back">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="flipped front bar back">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="front flipped back">fica em laranja</div>
<div class="bar front flipped back">fica em laranja</div>
```

---

Aproveite e de uma lida nesta pergunta:

- [O que é exatamente o seletor elemento.classe?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/58001/3635)

Answer (score 2):

```
.back.flipped
```

Significa um elemento que possui tanto a classe `.back` quanto `.flipped`.

```
.flipped
```

Significa um elemento que possui apenas a classe `.flipped`.

### ADICIONAL:

`.back .flipped` (separados)

Significa um elemento com a classe `.flipped` dentro de um elemento com a classe `.back`:

```
<div class="back">
    <input class="flipped" type="text" />
</div>
```